# var not accessible/visible within $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, callback, getjson

First off, know that I am very new noob. The code below works except for the "if" portion of the "if-else" portion. The "searchTerm" that is alerted is the last value that a user enters into an input field with multiple values. So if user enters "a, b, c, d", and "a" (or any other value) meet the ===0 criteria, "d" is what is alerted.

I have researched here in stackoverflow and googled other areas and learning about callbacks and promises and that .getJSON is asynchronous and visibility outside of JSON and such but I have to admit I'm obviously not getting it and I'm sure I'm missing something simple. Any insight/help will be greatly appreciated.

```
for (var l = 0; l < searchTermArray.length; l++) {
    searchTerm = searchTermArray[l];
    searchURL = buildURL(searchTerm);
    getResults(searchURL, searchTerm);
    function getResults() {
        $.getJSON(searchURL, function (responses) {
            presentResults(responses, searchTerm);
        });
    }
    function presentResults(responses, searchTerm) {
        response = responses.search;
        if (responses.search.return.count === 0) {
            alert(searchTerm + " Not Found");
        } else {
            alert("Results found");
            ****Do other stuff with the results****
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: What's the issue you are experiencing? I don't understand your problem? If is working but if else not???

Comment: @Volem , the issue is that the value that is alerted when I alert "searchTerm" within the if statement is not the value that met the criteria of ===0. Rather, the value alerted is the last value in the values entered. So if 4 values are entered and the 2nd value ===0, regardless, the last value is the one that is alerted. So it goes correctly into in the if but the value of searchTerm is incorrect.

Comment: Got it know sorry for bothering you on re-explaining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and separated the functions away from the for loop and then wrapped the .getJSON in a function of its own and passed the searchURL and searchTerm parameters which allowed me to works with the searchTerm for which the criteria was met.

```
function getResults(searchURL, searchTerm) {
   responses = '';
   $.getJSON(searchURL, function (responses) {
       presentResults(responses, searchTerm);
   }); // close JSON 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that for loop is not waiting for your asynchronous getjson. Searchurl and search term is overridden by every iteration. That is why you always get the last search term. Write a function and pass all the search urls and callback from it.

I hope this will lead you to the solution.

PS: Your function definitions are also inside the for loop which is not preferred.